# Bitcoin RPC Call

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I want to monitoring 3000 address continuously for BTC. So I am using third party API for get BTC balance. but all API has limitations for access. Can I get an API reference where I can call API continuously without any limitations?

If I will call API continuously then they will block my IP. So is there any way to short out this issue ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your own server and don't use a third party in such a case.
Take a look on "insight" of bitpay.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. I am also thinking for that. I am familiar with NEO blockchain. I have never use Bitcoin node in my current project. I have use only Bitcoin and Ethereum's API. So please can you guide me that how should I setup bitcoin node on my system.

Comment: see: https://insight.is/ and https://github.com/bitpay/insight